# F# custom operator with 3 parameters

Tags: f#, fantomas

I found the following piece of code in the fantomas library for F#. I am having a hard time understanding this as an F# noob. From what I understand, it's a custom operator that takes 3 arguments, but why would an operator need 3 arguments? And what exactly is happening here?

```
/// Function composition operator
let internal (+>) (ctx: Context -> Context) (f: _ -> Context) x =
    let y = ctx x

    match y.WriterModel.Mode with
    | ShortExpression infos when
        infos
        |> Seq.exists (fun x -> x.ConfirmedMultiline)
        ->
        y
    | _ -> f y
```

Here's an example of how fantomas uses this operator in ther `CodePrinter` module.

```
    let short =
        genExpr astContext e1
        +> sepSpace
        +> genInfixOperator "=" operatorExpr
        +> sepSpace
        +> genExpr astContext e2
```

Answer (score 2):

Operators behave a lot like function names:

```
let (++) a b c d =
    a + b + c + d

(++) 1 2 3 4
```

One difference is that operators can be used infix. An operator with more than 2 arguments allows infix only for the first 2 arguments:

```
// the following is equal:
let f = (++) 1 2 // like a function name
let f = 1 ++ 2   // with infix
f 50 60
```

I did not find how fantomas uses the operator you mention, would be curious, in particular since fantomas is a high profile f# project.

Comment: It's about building up a "final" function via a compositional pipeline.

Comment: fantomas uses this operator a lot in their ```CodePrinter``` module. I've posted an example in the question.

Comment: @citykid: so, can an operator that receives more than 2 arguments be used as infix? and if yes, how? you didn't answer the question

Comment: i provided an example in the answer above. you can use it to curry the first 2 args using infix.

Answer (score 1):

It might be instructive to compare this to the regular function composition operator, `>>`. The definition for this is:

```
let (>>) (f : a' -> b') (g : b' -> c') (x : a') =
   g ( f x )
```

Esentially, it applies `f` to `x`, and then applies `g` to the result.

If we have the following functions:

```
let plusOne i = i + 1
let timesTwo j = j * 2
```

And apply it the following way:

```
let plusOneTimesTwo = plusOne >> timesTwo
```

What we're really doing is something like this:

```
let plusOneTimesTwo = (>>) plusOne timesTwo
```

When you don't supply all of the necessary arguments to a function (in this case, `x`), what you get is a function that takes the remaining arguments and then returns what the original function would return (this is [partial application](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/).) In this case, `plusOneTimesTwo`'s function signature is now `x : int -> int`.

The example you've listed is essentially the same thing, but it's performing additional logic to determine whether it wants to apply the second function to the result `y` or to return it as-is.